# How can I load an array of images to be faded?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code where I am loading only one image. But I want to load multiple images from e folder and then to fade them in and out. But what I am interesting in, is how can I load all images from a folder without to repeat the code, as src="frames/frame_1" src="frames/frame_2" i want something soft as src="frames/frame_" + i + ".jpg" where i is the number of the frame

this is how I load only one image now

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('foo');

img.onload = function() {
  div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'frames/frame_1.jpg';
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively simple. You basically put the code you already had in a loop:

```
var img, i,
    imageCount = 5,
    div = document.getElementById('foo');

for(i = 0; i < imageCount; i++){
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        div.appendChild(img);
    };
    img.src = 'frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop `for` :

```js
var img,
    div = document.getElementById('foo');

for (var i = 0, nbImg = 5; i < nbImg; i++) {
  img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    div.appendChild(img);
  };

  img.src = 'frames/frame_'+i+'.jpg';
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest against using `var` statements in loops.